# Permission denied error when trying to run postgresql on Homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I ran `brew install postgresql`:

1. Then `brew services start postgresql`

Received
`Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /Users/$USER/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

2. Ran
   `chmod 755 ~/Library/LaunchAgents` and
   `cp /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/` (from https://coreyward.svbtle.com/fixing-homebrew-postgres-installation-on-macos-catalina)

This gave me `Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/$USER/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

3. I tried various things from this thread https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/7732946 but with no success.

I'm not too familiar with Homebrew and am wondering how to resolve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I'm running on a Macbook Air m1.

When I ran:

```
brew services start postgresql
```

I got the following error:

```
Error: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

Instead of doing what you posted I did the following:

```
sudo chown <username> /Users/<username>/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

And that made it work.
I got the idea from this github thread: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/177#issuecomment-450432567

Answer (score 0):

You can run these two commands, it is working for me.

```
% chmod 755 ~/Library/LaunchAgents
% cp /usr/local/opt/postgresql/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents/
```

To read more about what's going on, you can check below link :
Source : https://coreyward.svbtle.com/fixing-homebrew-postgres-installation-on-macos-catalina